# How to integrate spring authorization server into keycloak as OIDC an identity proivider

Tags: spring-security, spring-authorization-server

i have implemented a simple authorization server with Spring boot.my goal is to use it as an OIDC identity provider an register it with keycloak.
this is my configuration:

```
@Configuration
@Import(OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.class)
public class AuthorizationServerConfig {
    @Bean
    public RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository() {
        RegisteredClient registeredClient = RegisteredClient.withId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .clientId("client")
                .clientSecret("{noop}secret")
                .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_BASIC)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS)
                .redirectUri("http://KEYCLOAK_URL:8082/*")
                .scope(OidcScopes.OPENID)
                .build();

        return new InMemoryRegisteredClientRepository(registeredClient);
    }

    @Bean
    UserDetailsService users() {
        UserDetails user = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                .username("admin")
                .password("admin")
                .roles("ADMIN")
                .build();
        UserDetails user2 = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                .username("test")
                .password("test")
                .roles("USER")
                .build();
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user,user2);
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
    public SecurityFilterChain authServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);
        return http.formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults()).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwkSource() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        RSAKey rsaKey = generateRsa();
        JWKSet jwkSet = new JWKSet(rsaKey);
        return (jwkSelector, securityContext) -> jwkSelector.select(jwkSet);
    }

    private static RSAKey generateRsa() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        KeyPair keyPair = generateRsaKey();
        RSAPublicKey publicKey = (RSAPublicKey) keyPair.getPublic();
        RSAPrivateKey privateKey = (RSAPrivateKey) keyPair.getPrivate();
        return new RSAKey.Builder(publicKey)
                .privateKey(privateKey)
                .keyID(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .build();
    }

    private static KeyPair generateRsaKey() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        keyPairGenerator.initialize(2048);
        return keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
    }
    @Bean
    public ProviderSettings providerSettings() {
        return ProviderSettings.builder()
                .issuer("http://AUTH_SRVER_URL:9000")
                .build();
    }




}
```

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class DefaultSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       http.authorizeRequests()
               .antMatchers("/login")
               .permitAll()
               .anyRequest()
               .authenticated()
               .and()
               .formLogin();
        return http.build();
    }



}
```

then i registered the string authorization server as an idp in keycloak.
when i perform "login_with_spring" it redirects me to spring auth server login page. after submitting the form, it doesn't redirect me back to keycloak.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've configured `client_credentials` as the grant type, but are attempting to use it with OpenID Connect 1.0. OIDC works with the `authorization_code` grant type. I haven't tested the setup you are describing here, but I believe you can simply use instead:

```
.authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
```

Comment: thanks for replying. I changed my configuration and i added the authorization_code grant type, but i'am facing an exception of `Circular view path [error]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/error] again. Check your ViewResolver setup! (Hint: This may be the result of an unspecified view, due to default view name generation`

Comment: @RaoufRhimi it would be simpler if you update the config